# json2csv and fs module for nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to format my json file to csv file so I can use it in Google Sheets. So far I had succeed it. But my object of personalInfo is in one cell in Google Sheets and not seperate in two cells.

Here is the json file, which is an array of objects:

```
  [{
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "phone": "000 000 000",
            "personalInfo": 
                 {
                 "firstName": "John",
                 "lastName": "doe"
                 }
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

const fields = ['email', 'phone', 'personalInfo'];
const opts = { fields };
    
const parser = new Parser(opts);
const csv = parser.parse(new_arr);
    
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
});
```

I tried to add 'firstName' and 'lastName' in my const fields but it only add the title name to column and the object 'personalInfo' is still in one cell (which is not one cell for 'firstName' and 'lastName')

Comment: `I'm trying to format my json file to csv file so I can use it in Google Sheets.` ... if your goal is to use in google sheets, why don't you parse the json directly to GSheets ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the path properly.

i.e.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

const fields = ['email', 'phone', 'personalInfo.firstName', 'personalInfo.lastName'];
const opts = { fields };
    
const parser = new Parser(opts);
const csv = parser.parse(new_arr);
    
fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
});
```

From the docs you can also use `flatten` :

```js
// Default
flatten();

// Custom separator '__'
flatten({ separator: '_' });

// Flatten only arrays
flatten({ objects: false, arrays: true });
```